# CoreData Relationship between entities and attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm having a little trouble grasping CoreData relationships, i'm note sure which relationship type I should be using between my 2 entities or if my logic is correct.

1) "Person" Entity - attributes such as name, tel, address, country, etc...

2) "CountryList" - attributes such as countryName, countryLat, countryLong, etc..

The CountryList entity is pre populated on first run of the app to include all the countries in the world and their respected data.

Where i'm stuck is do I need a relationship between these two entities?

I will be allowing the user to select a country from the CountryList entity data and wish to store there selection in the country attribute for Person entity.

Do I just take the countryName from CountryList as a string and store it in country from Person? or can I make a relationship between them?

I know a user can only belong to 1 country but a country can have lots of users so is this a one to many relationship? Or is it many to many because lots of users can belong to a country but a country can have loads of users? Confused!

Could someone please enlighten me on this and point me in the right direction in what i should be doing in xcode.

Many Thanks in Advance
Matt

**EDIT: Is this correct?**

I have made the changes to Entity names etc and think I now have the relationship set correctly.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

**EDIT 2: Removed country attribute and renamed relationships**

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: If you are confused how to implement relationships let me know.. I am currently working on Core Data only and did all this stuff.. So always happy to help.. :-))

Comment: Looks good now, but as I said, rename the relationships. Also, you won't need the "country" attribute in "Person" anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your "CountryList" entity should be called "Country", since it represents only one country. The fact that you have many of those countries has nothing to do with its name.

After that, it seems just natural to use a relationship, one "Person" has one "Country", but one country can have many persons. Therefore, one-to-many relationship. Using a relationship will simplify many operations you might want to perform (i.e. access all the country information of one person, or get a list of all persons being in one particular country).

Oh, and this might help you understand relationships a bit better: There are no "many-to-many" relationships in CoreData per se. You always define a relation from a source to a target. So if you define a relation from Country to Person, this will be a one-to-many relationship. One country, many persons. You can then define a relationship from Person to Country, which would be a one-to-one relationship. One person, one country. If you defined this as an one-to-many relationship, you would end up with a de facto many-to-many relationship (because on person can have many countries and one country can have many persons). It's not as complex as it appears.

Now, after you've defined your two relationships, you can set them as each others "Inverse Relationship". Do it for one of the relationships, the other one will be set automatically. After you did that, CoreData will for example update a Person's country when you add the person to the country's list.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html for further information.

Comment: Please have look at my answer and kindly prompt if my suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @JiaYow Many Thanks, I think this is where I'm getting a little confused thinking of CoreData like a database and assuming Entities are like tables. Which I know isn't the case, but hard find it hard to think otherwise. So in xcode I select Person entity and create relationship countryRel and then select Country entity and create personRel and set their Inverse. Then select personRel relationship under Country entity and select To-Many Relationship? I think this seems right.

Comment: Yup. But skip the "Rel" parts. Call the relationship "country" and "persons" (you'll have many persons, therefore plural) respectively. It's far more intuitive to use

Comment: @JiaYow Thanks again, its great to not just have an answer but you also given some "Best Practice" advice :D Please check the screenshot in my original post to see if I have it correct now. I will make the changes to Relationship names in my project

Comment: @JiaYow I can't call the relationship country because I have a country attribute in the Person entity. Is that correct?

Comment: @MattPrice you don't need the country attribute anymore. The relationship now fulfills its role

Comment: @JiaYow Once again many thanks for your help and full response to my question.

Answer (score 0):

`CountryList` should just be `Country`

Then you set a 'many to one' relationship between Person.county and Country

Answer (score 0):

You are using Core Data so you must define relationship between `Person` and `Country` if you want to fetch person's country from database.

And in this relationship you may take one to one relationship. As One person will belong to one country only. Of Course a country will have many person but unless you want to show all people related to particular country you do not need one to many relationship..

In case you want to implement one to many relationship [**this**](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/09/29/iphone-app-development-tutorial-core-data-part-2-one-to-many-relationship/) tutorial link maybe helpful to you for understanding one to many relationship..

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/09/29/iphone-app-development-tutorial-core-data-part-2-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Note that this is true for the relation Person->Country, not for Country->Person (if he wants that too)

Comment: @JiaYow : Yeah thats what I was trying tell but I explained it in little tough language.. Thanks buddy.. :-))

Comment: I do want to be able to get all Persons for a particular Country. So its One-to-Many?

Comment: Yes.. Than..You will have to check that option to-many relationship from model inspector on right...